# Creating Folder structure

Tags: asp.net

I need to develop the following folder structure in an application dynamically.i have developed it using jQuery.is there any alternative way to develop this structure in asp.net.

Actually i am creating a ul li structure and i am adding folder icon to ul itenm and file icon to li item fro m code behind.once if the ul structure is created i am using a jquery plugin to show this ul structure as folders and file in the browser..i just want to show the structure..

[image]

Comment: Are you creating it client-side or server-side? You state you did it using jQuery, which suggests client-side, but I don't even understand how that is possible as JavaScript sandboxing will not allow directories to be created. Assuming you want to create it server-side, creating a directory is trivial in .Net, so please clarify exactly what you are having problems with.

Comment: where you want to create this directory...? in Client Machine Or Server Machine...? in Client means Which Location...?

Comment: i am creating in client side that folder,file icons are added through code..

Comment: @Gajawada But it's not possible to create a folder on the client's machine. JavaScript security restrictions will prevent it! Please can you edit your question to describe **exactly** what you are currently doing, and **exactly** what you hope to achieve, and **exactly** what is preventing you achieving it.

Comment: Actually i have created a <ul><li></li></ul> structure in code behind.to that ul i  have used a jquery plugin which shows that list as Folders,but i dont want to use jquery..

Comment: i just want to show the above structure to the user.i dont want to create any new folders over there..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Treeview in asp.net - the treeview supports binding images to the nodes.

```
<asp:TreeView id="SampleTreeView" 
  runat="server">
    <RootNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/Images/root.gif" />
    <ParentNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/Images/parent.gif" />
    <LeafNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/Images/leaf.gif" />
  <Nodes>
    <asp:TreeNode Value="Home" 
      Text="Home"
      Target="Content" 
      Expanded="True">
      <asp:TreeNode Value="Page 1" 
        Text="Page1"
        Target="Content">
        <asp:TreeNode Value="Section 1" 
          Text="Section 1"
          Target="Content"/>
      </asp:TreeNode>              
      <asp:TreeNode Value="Page 2" 
        Text="Page 2"
        Target="Content"
          ImageUrl="~/Images/star.gif">
      </asp:TreeNode> 
    </asp:TreeNode>
  </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

If you want to build the treeview dynamically - this resource may also be of help.  http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Asp-Control/AddingnodesprogrammaticallytotheTreeViewcontrolC.htm